# Does the [Twilio] Transcription Post request appear in call's Request Inspector

Tags: twilio

Does the transcription callback post request that Twilio sends after a transcription appear in the Request Inspector? I am not getting the request, or it is not triggering the actions I expect, and I was hoping to use the details in the inspector as I did for the other actions.

Here is my code that triggers the transcription request

> `<Record action="record_complete?PersonId=6" transcribeCallback="/twilioplugin/transcription?PersonId=6" method="GET"/>`

Comment: I'm a developer evangelist at Twilio and I'm finding I don't get the callback right now either. Following up with the team internally, hopefully we can find out why. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sadly the `transcribeCallback` is not shown in the request inspector at all.

If you are working with transcribe callbacks in development, I recommend using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to open a tunnel to your local application and then checking on the requests with the ngrok dashboard which is available at http://127.0.0.1:4040 when ngrok is running. You can see more detail on this in my blog post on [useful ngrok features](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html). The dashboard shows you all requests, the details from them and allows you to replay requests.

Let me know if this helps at all.